# How to schedule a script in  SQL Server Express  ( without SQL Server Agent )?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, scheduling

Ok so I asked a question yesterday about doing a timed procedure. I got some responses about using SQL Server Agent but i found out that I am using Sql server 2008 express RC and its not available.

Here is my first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748961/sql-server-timed-procedure) and I want to know if there is another tool I can use to do a timed procedure with sql server ....thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can use scheduled task (control panel-administrative tools) and start a .cmd/.bat file where you use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) to execute SP's or run scripts.

`sqlcmd` is a command line tool. `sqlcmd /?` will show you what you can do with it.

[image]

Here is how you can use `sqlcmd` to execute a SP called StoredProcName in database YourDatabase on server instance ComputerName\sqlexpress.

```
sqlcmd -S ComputerName\sqlexpress -E -d YourDatabase -Q "exec StoredProcName"
```

Read more about Using the sqlcmd Utility here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

Read about the Task Scheduler here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: what do you mean by start a .cmd/.bat file...im more of a mac guy and this windows env is new to me...also is sqlcmd a command or a stand alone program

Comment: @Tamer - Updated answer with some more info. I think you don't have to use bat/cmd file. You can use the sqlcmd utility directly from Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dialog timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) to start [activated procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx). This functionality is available on the Express edition. The advantage over an external service, like Windows Scheduler, is that the solution is self contained inside the database. For example you can move the database to a different computer and the timed procedure will still run, on the new computer, once the database is started. An external service requires you to reconfigure the scheduler agent on the new computer.

Comment: It is useful answer for my question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847994/every-minute-event-implementation-in-ms-sql-without-agent