# Every-minute event implementation in MS SQL without Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want my stored procedure to be executed every minute but I have no access to SQL Server Agent.

Comment: This answer might work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756516/sql-server-2008-express-rc-commands/5765997#5765997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Windows scheduler and sqlcmd.exe would be easiest

Comment: hm.. the matter is I have no full access to the server tools. It is remote hosting and I think hosters will not give me access to the Windows scheduler. But first of all, I'll ask them. Thank for solution.

Comment: Is it a website? If it is ASP.net you could implement Quartz.net to do this pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a program that executes your procedure onxe a minute, and keep that program running.